# Picker like custom control for OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

Is there a [OSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) custom control or source code sample for doing something like the iOS Picker controls on Mac OS X (the spinning barrel thingie)?

[image]

A bit of research on the web and sites like http://www.cocoacontrols.com didn't turn up anything..

I realize that the paradigm will be awkward for many scenarios however it'll be ideal in terms of screen estate (and design) for the casual app I'm working on.

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to think about customizing available controls to create a spinning barrel effect. Haven't tried, but it might be overkill. I might think of using buttons with text for the contents (or a table view with custom cells), and/or a scroll view with animation for a scroll event. It might be a useful customization for Mac OS X, without consideration for the fact that UIPickerView was meant for a touch screen.

Edit: This might be a start in the direction you want to be going. -> https://gist.github.com/1558664

Comment: Well, yeah - except it's unlike anything else to sounds like quite a bit of non-trivial work :-)  I guess I'd go with some boring standard control if there's not already a decent implementation out there.

Comment: Just because a standard control is "boring" does not mean that it is unusable. Porting a picker to OS X might look nice, but its quite the wrong paradigm for the desktop.